# Set Binding Null Value For TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a string binding for my textbox.text property and as soon as the binding is null nothing is displayed inside my textbox. However I want to display a different text instead of String.Empty

In wpf there is a property TargetNullValue and it worked there for me. But I can't find an equivalent in WinForms NullValue, DataSourceNullValue are not doing the same thing for me...

So here my code example

```
list= new BindingList<item>();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = list;

Binding tbBinding= new Binding("Text", bs, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
tb.DataBindings.Add(tbBinding);
```

the binding works fine until the list is empty. I don't know how to specify the null value properly

EDIT:

new code snippet

```
        selectedSweeps = new BindingList<Sweep>();
        BindingSource bsSweep = new BindingSource();
        bsSweep.DataSource = selectedSweeps;
        lbSelectedSweeps.DataSource = bsSweep;
        lbSelectedSweeps.DisplayMember = "DisplayText";

        Binding nameBinding = new Binding("Text", bsSweep, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        nameBinding.NullValue = "error text";
        tbSweepName.DataBindings.Add(nameBinding);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add-in a TextChanged event for your textbox.
Go to the designer, double click the textbox and following event will show up in code:
Add code between brackets for checking .Text property.

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check if .Text property of textbox is equal to null or is empty.
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))
    {
        //Set Default empty value here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to update before current of my list binding is null. That means I would bind it to selectedindexchanged and check for index < 0 and put my code inside. 

But still I want to find a cleaner solution, maybe with data binding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [Binding Constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158047%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that uses a custom format string.

That is instead of

```csharp
Binding tbBinding= new Binding(
        "Text", 
        bs, 
        "Name", 
        true, 
        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

try something like

```csharp
Binding tbBinding= new Binding(
        "Text", 
        bs, 
        "Name", 
        true, 
        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
        "[not specified]");
```

Comment: as I mentioned null value does not seem to work for me ... my tb stays empty

Comment: @SilvioMarcovic That's strange because I tried it before posting my answer and it worked for me.

Comment: hmm i updated my code snippet with a more concrete example but I don't think this will make any difference